# How to print an item the size and thickness of a laptop display?

Tags: 3d-models, creality-ender-3

I want to print a case for a laptop display that I plan to turn into a second display. I have the `Ender 3` printer, with a print area smaller than the case's size.

I know I need to make it modular, but I am not sure of

- the best way to print something that is so large and relatively thin, so the connectors between the pieces are strong enough to hold it together (due to the large size compared to the thickness, i don't think regular [snap or plug conectors](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/736/tips-for-making-parts-that-push-snap-together) will suffice)
- how to stop the layers from coming apart because the longer it is, the
  more pressure applied to the join points if it flexes.

Any help you can give will be greatly appreciated.

Liam.

Comment: The answers to the first part of the question may probably found in the answers to [this question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/736/150) , [this question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/2750/150) or [this question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/4814/150)

Comment: Design for fitting together with pegs, and glue.